# Is it always safe to use `eval echo`?

Tags: bash, echo

Using `eval` is often discouraged because it allows execution of arbitrary code. However, if we use `eval echo`, then it looks like the rest of the string will become arguments of `echo` so it should be safe. Am I correct on this?

Comment: not always safe you could wrap a fork bomb or nasty rm -fR *

Comment: Maybe this is just a thought experiment, but if you were actually thinking of doing this to pass it multiple arguments like `-n`, you can just do it with an unquoted variable like `echo $arguments` or if `$arguments` is an array `echo "${arguments[@]}"`. Using `eval echo` is pointless even if it _were_ safe.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Counterexample:

```
DANGEROUS=">foo"
eval echo $DANGEROUS
```

The arbitrary arguments to `echo` could have done something more nefarious than creating a file called "foo".

Comment: Also: `DANGEROUS="hello;ls"`, for arbitrary commands in place of `ls`.

Comment: Also: `DANGEROUS='$(ls)'` (more escaping may be required).

Comment: Would `eval echo '"'"$DANGEROUS"'"'` work? It seems to on https://goo.gl/L2pPQP

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That doesn't work for wizzwizz, Cyker, or sorontar's examples, or for anything with double-quotes in the string (e.g. `DANGEROUS='">foo"'`).

Comment: Darn. I though I found something that helped a little

Comment: Or `DANGEROUS='whatever; reboot'`. IOW, the content of $DANGEROUS doesn't necessarily become arguments to `echo`.

Comment: Even that would be bad if `foo` already existed and (for some reason) had something important in it that couldn't be easily replaced.

Answer (score 27):

@Celada has provided an excellent answer. To demonstrate `eval` is really evil, here's *something more nefarious than creating a file called "foo"*:

```
DANGEROUS='$(rm foo)'
eval echo "$DANGEROUS"
```

And of course there can be *something more nefarious than something more nefarious than creating a file called "foo"*.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating that quoting the variable like `"$THIS"` instead of just having it like `$THIS` doesn't even help!

Comment: Sending an aditional pair of quotes seems to help. Something like `eval echo '"'"$DANGEROUS"'"'`. Try it on https://goo.gl/L2pPQP

Comment: Actually, your example isn't any more nefarious than `>foo`, because "creating a file called 'foo'" isn't necessarily all that `>foo` does. The only real difference your example has is that it doesn't leave an empty file behind. The contents are still gone.

Answer (score 12):

No, it is **not** always safe. An eval could execute any command.

A safe command, like this (the date is not executed as it is inside single quotes):

```
$ echo '$(date)'
$(date)
```

Becomes dangerous if used with eval:

```
$ eval echo '$(date)'
Sat Dec 24 22:55:55 UTC 2016
```

Of course, date could be **any** command.

One way to improve this is to additionally quote the arguments to eval:

```
$ eval echo '\$(date)'
$(date)
```

But it is usually difficult to correctly quote twice an expression.

And it becomes impossible to control the correct quoting if the expression could be set by an external attacker, like:

```
$ var='$(date);echo Hello!'
$ eval echo "$var"
Sat Dec 24 23:01:48 UTC 2016
Hello!
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that `eval` always needs to be approached with caution, the `eval echo` construction is not always pointless and *can* be used safely. I recently needed it to get multiple brace expansions evaluated in the order I needed them done.

`bash` does multiple brace expansions from left to right, so

```
xargs -I_ cat _/{11..15}/{8..5}.jpg
```

expands to

```
xargs -I_ cat _/11/8.jpg _/11/7.jpg _/11/6.jpg _/11/5.jpg _/12/8.jpg _/12/7.jpg _/12/6.jpg _/12/5.jpg _/13/8.jpg _/13/7.jpg _/13/6.jpg _/13/5.jpg _/14/8.jpg _/14/7.jpg _/14/6.jpg _/14/5.jpg _/15/8.jpg _/15/7.jpg _/15/6.jpg _/15/5.jpg
```

but I needed the second brace expansion done first, yielding

```
xargs -I_ cat _/11/8.jpg _/12/8.jpg _/13/8.jpg _/14/8.jpg _/15/8.jpg _/11/7.jpg _/12/7.jpg _/13/7.jpg _/14/7.jpg _/15/7.jpg _/11/6.jpg _/12/6.jpg _/13/6.jpg _/14/6.jpg _/15/6.jpg _/11/5.jpg _/12/5.jpg _/13/5.jpg _/14/5.jpg _/15/5.jpg
```

The best I could come up with to do that was

```
xargs -I_ cat $(eval echo _/'{11..15}'/{8..5}.jpg)
```

This works because the single quotes protect the first set of braces from expansion during the parsing of the `eval` command line, leaving them to be expanded by the subshell invoked by `eval`.

There may be some cunning scheme involving nested brace expansions that allows this to happen in one step, but if there is I'm too old and stupid to see it. There are also shells other than `bash` that allow for tidier ways of achieving this kind of thing. But in any case, this use of `eval` is safe because its arguments are all fixed strings that contain no parameter expansions.

Comment: You don't need echo and the command substitution here (which also has a dependency on $IFS). You could do `eval  xargs -I_ cat _/'{11..15}'/{8..5}.jpg`

Comment: That works too, but it makes the subshell process spawned by eval stick around until the xargs process is finished; the eval echo version makes that subshell go away before xargs is even started. This is probably only important to others who are as anal as me about what shows up in htop tree views and set -x logs though :-)