# Why can't I convert a string variable into an array when some items include spaces?

Tags: bash, array, bash-array

For example, in the snippet below, (how) is it possible to make `array2` identical to `array1` while still using a `str` variable?

```
~$ { str='a "b c" d'; array1=(a "b c" d); array2=( $str )
  echo "${array1[1]} ${array1[2]}"
  echo "${array2[1]} ${array2[2]}"; }

b c d
"b c"
```

Comment: my output is different...

Comment: you did not quote `$str` - even if `"$str"` you just give printable chars like `\"b c\"` and not actually quoted string `"b c"` (only eval would execute quotes)

Comment: @pLumo Do you also get two different arrays?

Comment: Sure. The quotes are taken literal and have no special meaning for the variable, they are just a character like any other. While when assigning the array using quotes, the quotes are evaluated from your shell to separate the arguments.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the end? Can you skip the string variable and just do `array=(a "b c" d)`?

Comment: @ilkkachu I can, in some cases, but I still needed a simple way to get an array out of an otherwise correctly formatted variable.

Comment: `str='a b[[:space:]]c d'` should work too (bash) or can be converted automatically (before passing into `$str`) like `string="b c"; string="${string//[[:space:]]/[[:space:]]}"; str="a $string d";` (will mask all space, tab, newline, linefeed, formfeed, vertical tab in `$string`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `str='a "b c" d'`, the quotes are taken literal and have no special meaning afterwards, they are just a character like any other and do not prevent [word splitting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26661/what-is-word-splitting-why-is-it-important-in-shell-programming) anymore.

While when assigning the array using quotes, the quotes are evaluated from your shell before the assignment to prevent word splitting:

```
array1=(a "b c" d);
```

---

Btw: Using `printf` is a bit easier to showcase the issue then setting up an array and using a loop to `echo` the elements:

```
printf '%s\n' $str
```

You might use `eval` as a workaround, but [I would not recommend doing that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332579/is-it-always-safe-to-use-eval-echo) for any input you cannot 100% control or trust (user input, webscraping stuff, etc.):

```
eval "printf '%s\n' $str"
#or
eval "array2=( $str )"
```

Anyways, from your example, I see no reason to use an intermediate variable, just use arrays directly.

Comment: of course. Because the quotes are lost as special shell characters when you set up the variable. I mean it's easier to showcase the issue using `printf` then setting up an array and using a loop to `echo` the element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, by using `eval`.

Thank you all for confirming the type of quoting problem.

Simply use `eval "array2=( $str )"` instead of `array2=( $str )`.

*Note, however, that using `eval` is often a bad idea.*

Comment: Just don't use `eval` with any untrusted input. It would process all expansions and e.g. semicolons. if `str='$(evilcmd) foo'`, then `eval "array2=( $str )"` would run `evilcmd` and put the output in `array2`

Comment: Thank you for the warning. Actually your comment is a very important addition to this answer.