# why does a=$(eval echo hello world) not error out?

Tags: bash, shell

I stumbled over this: Boiled down the example is

```bsh
/ # a=$(eval echo hello world)
/ # echo $a
hello world
/ # $(eval echo hello world)
/bin/sh: hello: not found
/ # a=$(hello world)
/bin/sh: hello: not found
```

I would expect that the first line expands to `hello world` inside the parentheses and is then expanded the same way the last line is: `a=$(hello world)`. After all `help eval` tells us:

> Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell, and execute the resulting commands.

If eval does execute the resulting command before expansion of `$()` takes place—which I expect—the result should be an error for `hello world` is not executable (unless there is an actual `hello` command)

**Why does** `a=$(eval echo hello world)` **not error out as expected**?

Comment: I would suggest not experimenting with bash features while logged in a root.

Comment: Thx 4 your kind advice but no worry: I ran it inside a docker container.

Comment: I kinda want to ask _why_ you expect that first one would error out. As in, if there's some particular way you think it should work, that would then lead to an error.

Comment: My train of thought was: `eval echo hello world` expands to `hello world` so basically I expected after expansion it would be equal to the last line `a=$(hello world)`.

Comment: @karlsebal When command substitution is expanded `$(..)` is replaced by the output of the commands ran inside. So the `$(..)` is no longer present once `eval echo` is ran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If eval does execute the resulting command before expansion of $() takes place—which I expect—the result should be an error for hello world is not executable (unless there is an actual hello command)

That is not how substitution works. The mere presence of `$(..)` is what causes the `eval` to even run

---

To start with, [`$(..)` Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) in bash is a way to capture the output of command run inside parens and storing it in a variable. The `$(..)` is replaced by output of contents present inside it

1. The part `a=$(eval echo hello world)` is executed by the shell in following order. The `eval echo hello world` is executed simply as `echo hello world` which runs the echo command and outputs the string `hello world` which is stored into the variable `a`.
2. The part `$(eval echo hello world)` just returns `hello world` as explained in 1). But there is no assignment to capture the output of `$(..)` anywhere. So a literal string is returned back to the shell i.e. `hello world`. The shell tries to interpret that as a command (the literal `hello` string). Hence the error you see, that a command not found of the name
3. The same happens for `a=$(hello world)` also. As mentioned in 1), the part `$(..)` runs the contents inside the parens as commands. So the literal string is evaluated again resulting in the same error.

In cases 2) and 3), when the `$(..)` is expanded, the literal unquoted string `hello world` was returned back to the shell which was subject to word splitting causing `hello` and `world` as two separate words. Thats why you encounter the error that `hello` was run as a command and not the whole string `hello world`.

---

Be cautious in using `eval` with any command, as simple as even `echo`. There is a risk of executing dangerous commands when not properly invoked. See [Is it always safe to use `eval echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332579/112235)

Comment: @karlsebal, in that particular case, `eval echo hello world` is the same as `echo hello world`. But in general, you have to look at the whole thing to see what the extra evaluation step caused by `eval` does. `eval echo '$BASH_VERSION'` is not the same as `echo '$BASH_VERSION'`.